# How to add a more generic event handler to an event at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, events, delegates

If I have a type that inherits from EventArgs (lets call it EventArgs1), and a further bunch of classes that inherit from EventArgs1 (lets call them collectively EventArgsX), and then a bunch of events that are are of the type `EventHandler<EventArgsX>`, if at runtime I am passed the EventInfo for one of these events and I want to add an event handler that expects a second argument of type EventArgs1 (e.g. `MyEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs1 e)`) how would I do it?

If the event was of type `EventHandler<EventArgs1>` then I would just do this:

```
eventInfo.AddEventHandler(this, new EventHandler<EventArgs1>(MyEventHandler));
```

But this throws an exception when the event is of type `EventHandler<EventArgsX>`, and since I don't know what EventArgsX is at compile time I can't simply new up an `EventHandler<EventArgsX>`  If I did know which event I was adding the handler to at compile time then this would be entirely acceptable:

```
MyEvent += MyEventHandler
```

But I simply can't work out how to do this at runtime. Any suggestions?

Comment: How are you even passing in multiple events?

Comment: Could you post some pseudocode with an example of what you'd like to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I can't simply new up an `EventHandler<EventArgsX>`

Sure you can, although you need to do it using [`Delegate.CreateDelegate()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9tz542wy.aspx) and reflection. Assuming `MyEventHandler` is an instance method on `this`, you could do it like this:

```
var eventInfo = …;

EventHandler<EventArgs1> badHandler = MyEventHandler;

var goodHandler = Delegate.CreateDelegate(
    eventInfo.EventHandlerType, this, badHandler.Method);

eventInfo.AddEventHandler(this, goodHandler);
```

Comment: That's worked brilliantly, thanks :). I was trying `Delegate.CreateDelegate()` but was getting a binding error so I'd obviously mistyped something (was rushing to try and get it done before end of a long day). Also, I was using GetMethod("MyEventHandler") but I much prefer your refactoring safe method.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

I have read the question backwards, essentially; I will leave this answer in case someone else who *is* trying to do the reverse finds this question.

---

<s>Basically, you can't do what you're trying to do.  An event can't add a delegate if the delegate's EventArgs type is a subclass of the event's declared type.  You're trying to use covariance when the input parameter is contravariant.</s>

Assume these classes

```
class EventArgs1 : EventArgs {}
class EventArgsA : EventArgs1 {}
class EventArgsB : EventArgs1 {}
```

Consider what would happen if you could add a method `void Handle(object sender, EventArgsA args)` to an event with the signature `void SomeEvent(object sender, EventArgs1 args)`.  The event source might do this:

```
if (SomeEvent != null)
{
    var args = new EventArgsB();
    SomeEvent(this, args);      //this line is perfectly legal, as EventArgsB inherits from EventArgs1.
}
```

However, when the runtime gets to this delegate in the event's invocation list, it now has to pass the `args` object to `Handle(object, EventArgsA)`, which it of course can't do, since an EventArgsB instance is not an EventArgsA instance.  A run-time exception would result.  In reality, the mismatch is caught when you add the delegate, so the exception is thrown then.

Comment: I think that's not what the question is asking. It's the other way around: the events use `EventArgsA/B/X` and the handler `EventArgs1`.

Comment: @svick Oh dear. I just re-read the question, and I suppose you're right.  End of a long day...

Comment: Thanks anyway phoog, easy mistake to make at the end of a day, and perhaps I didn't word it very clearly.

Comment: @BykerDave it's actually pretty clear ("I want to add an event handler that expects a second argument of type EventArgs1"); I just read it too quickly, I guess, and missed that bit.  I'm going to leave this answer in case anyone comes on this question who is in the position I thought you were in.